# R package installation location on windows

Tags: r

I have downloaded a package called **multicon** on a Windows machine which has R installed. It's a zip file. Where should I place that package/zip file so that R starts recognizing the functions defined in it?

Comment: Why not just install from CRAN? `install.packages("multicon")`, you can also do `install.packages("path/to/file", repos = NULL)`

Comment: OK, but where does that ultimately put them? If I use another Windows user will they still be there? At the end it said: "The downloaded binary packages are in C:\Users\Peter.Petrov\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0IWR3M\downloaded_packages" I think I want them under my R root folder.

Comment: That's where the binary is downloaded to, which isn't the same as the location to which the package gets more permanently installed. To find out where *that* is, when you do `install.packages()` without supplying a `lib=` argument,  check the value of `.libPaths()[1]` (as you'll learn by reading `?install.packages`).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien OK, so I thought. OK, got it. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Pascal Yeah, my question is a duplicate of this one. Thanks.